# Html.LabelFor helper in MVC2

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC2, Preview 2. Why is it that when I use:

```
        <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Nombres) %>
        <%= Html.Encode(Model.Nombres) %>
```

It outputs:

```
Nombre:
Sr. Fulano de Tal
```

But when I use:

```
        Nombres:
        <%= Html.Encode(Model.Nombres) %>
```

it outputs:

```
Nombre: Sr. Fulano de Tal
```

I don't want the return after the label. Is it my CSS that is ruining things, or is it the HTML.LabelFor that is producing the extra return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really hard to answer.  Could do with seeing the actual html markup it is producing. I suspect the labels are either floated or display:block in the css.

Comment: you are right, this has nothing to do with the Html.LabelFor method... It's with the CSS.

Comment: just a quick note.  Label tags should only be used in conjunction with input elements.  

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 0):

View Source will help you know what the right answer is here.  What is the HTML generated in each case?

I suspect that what's happening here is that the HTML element generated by `Html.LabelFor` is defined, in your CSS, as a [block element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#document_body_elements), meaning that subsequent content will start on a new line. If this is what's happening, you can change the CSS for those elements to use `display:inline;` and they should show up on the same line as your field's value. You can also use the `float` CSS attribute to generate the same effect, but floats are generally harder to work with than `display:inline`.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML output for your case should be something like: `<label for="Nombres">Nombre</label>`.
No `<br/>` is rendered, so the only answer should lie in the CSS, like Justin said. Look for css styles attached to "label" elements, or not so probable, something related to "Nombres".